# How do I alternate row colors in active admin without it displaying "odd" "even" in the view?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

For some reason when I use the 'odd', 'even' trick. It will also display the text on the view page above my table.  So it'll show "odd" "even" based on how many rows there are in the table.  It clutters up my page.

```
  panel 'Cities' do
        table do
          tbody do
            f.collection_check_boxes(:city_ids, City.select('id, name, state').order(:name), :id, :name_and_state) do |city|
              tr(class: cycle('odd', 'even')) do
                td(class: 'col col-checkbox') { city.check_box } +
                td(class: 'col col-text') do
                  city.label do
                    city.text
                  end
```

Here's a picture example
https://cloud.githubusercontent.com/assets/13935816/14294144/32040c28-fb35-11e5-9e97-ac3292b9ca86.png

Answer (score 0):

Refer this example.

```css
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
table{
  border-spacing:0;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
     <tr>
      <th>Month

      </th><th>'94

      </th><th>'95

      </th><th>'96

      </th><th>'97

      </th><th>'98

      </th><th>'99

      </th><th>'00

      </th><th>'01

      </th><th>'02

     </th></tr><tr>
      <td>Jan

      </td><td>14

      </td><td>13

      </td><td>14

      </td><td>13

      </td><td>14

      </td><td>11

      </td><td>11

      </td><td>11

      </td><td>11

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Feb

      </td><td>13

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>12

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>12

      </td><td>14

      </td><td>13

      </td><td>13

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Mar

      </td><td>16

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>14

      </td><td>17

      </td><td>16

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>14

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>15

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Apr

      </td><td>17

      </td><td>16

      </td><td>17

      </td><td>17

      </td><td>17

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>16

      </td><td>16

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>May

      </td><td>21

      </td><td>20

      </td><td>20

      </td><td>21

      </td><td>22

      </td><td>20

      </td><td>21

      </td><td>20

      </td><td>19

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Jun

      </td><td>24

      </td><td>23

      </td><td>25

      </td><td>24

      </td><td>25

      </td><td>23

      </td><td>25

      </td><td>23

      </td><td>24

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Jul

      </td><td>29

      </td><td>28

      </td><td>26

      </td><td>26

      </td><td>27

      </td><td>26

      </td><td>25

      </td><td>26

      </td><td>25

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Aug

      </td><td>29

      </td><td>28

      </td><td>27

      </td><td>28

      </td><td>28

      </td><td>27

      </td><td>26

      </td><td>28

      </td><td>26

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Sep

      </td><td>24

      </td><td>23

      </td><td>23

      </td><td>26

      </td><td>24

      </td><td>24

      </td><td>24

      </td><td>22

      </td><td>21

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Oct

      </td><td>20

      </td><td>22

      </td><td>20

      </td><td>22

      </td><td>20

      </td><td>19

      </td><td>20

      </td><td>22

      </td><td>

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Nov

      </td><td>18

      </td><td>17

      </td><td>16

      </td><td>17

      </td><td>16

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>14

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>

     </td></tr><tr>
      <td>Dec

      </td><td>15

      </td><td>13

      </td><td>13

      </td><td>14

      </td><td>13

      </td><td>10

      </td><td>13

      </td><td>11

      </td><td>
   </td></tr></tbody></table>
```